# How can i reload the current page in Ionic 3 when i refresh the browser?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I´ve the following problem. I´m working on an App written with Ionic 3 and I need that when I refresh the browser it renders the current page and does not redirect me to the home page.

It's possible?

I have tried with this code:

`this.navCtrl.setRoot (this.navCtrl.getActive (). component);`

But this deletes the browsing history of navController.

Forgive me for my level of English, it´s still very poor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with browser reloads you need to annotate your pages with @IonicPage. The Ionic Page handles registering and displaying specific pages based on URLs.

[Ionic Page docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/IonicPage/)